# WooCommerce plugin integration with custom theme

Tags: wordpress

I have my own html to display all products inserted in WooCommerce. But I am unable to show it in my styling. I have searched it but unable to find any good solution.

Please help.

Comment: why do not you custom edit Woocommerce templates instead of doing the opposite, just go to Woocommerce template files and edit them

Comment: in which template i can edit styling of products showing?

Comment: Google edit Woocommerce templates and you will have enough explantation

Answer (score 0):

You have to learn about wordpress templates hierarchy that all files how it works?

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

Suppose You want to create **single page** of product then create a new file into your theme with name **single-product.php** then single product url automatically render this file.

As same you want to create **shop page (Where all products should shown)** then create a file into your theme with name **archive-product.php** then shop page automatically render this File

For **add to Cart** functionality there are lots of plugin that can be used.